# WhatsApp Share button for blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger, whatsapp

I've a WhatsApp share button but I'm facing some issue with it. sharing function works well but the problem is that when the page loads(or while leaving the page), the background color of the button is displayed on the entire page for a short period of time which looks ugly. Can somebody help me to fix it? What should I change in this code so that the original theme color will be displayed while page loading instead of this WhatsApp button's color? Thanks in advance.

```
<style>
body{background-color:#49C34F}
.mct_whatsapp_btn {
    background: #11A518;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 6px 9px 6px 28px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
    transition: ease-in all 0.3s;
    moz-transition: ease-in all 0.3s;
    -o-transition:ease-in all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: ease-in all 0.3s;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 1px 1px rgba(17, 165, 24, 0.25);
    border: 1px solid #028408;
}

.mct_whatsapp_btn:before {
    content: '';
    background: url(BACKGROUND IMAGE URL);
    position:absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 7px;
    width:16px;
    transition: ease-in all 0.3s;
    moz-transition: ease-in all 0.3s;
    -o-transition:ease-in all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: ease-in all 0.3s;
    height:16px;
}

.mct_whatsapp_btn:hover {
    background: #028408;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    border: 1px solid #11A518;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 1px 1px rgba(2, 132, 8, 0.25);
}

.mct_whatsapp_btn:hover:before {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 well">


    <a class="mct_whatsapp_btn" data-link="" data-text="" href="whatsapp://send?text=">Share</a>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first block of code `body{background-color:#49C34F}`

Comment: Thanks Bassam. Let me try

Comment: Thanks a lot  Bassam. It's working fine now. Thanks again